# Multiple APK in Android Market

Tags: android, google-play, apk

I just read about the [added multiple APK functionality](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/07/multiple-apk-support-in-android-market.html) in the Android Market developer dashboard. It seems to enable you to upload different APK's with the same package name targetting different devices.

However, could this functionality also be used to bundle APK's with different package names, so you can offer a pack of apps?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No.

Answer (score 2):

Hm....

"All APKs you publish for the same application must have the same package name and be signed with the same certificate key."